# Windows `CreateFileW` failing intermittently

Tags: windows, winapi, rust

I am calling [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) on `"C:\\"`, but it is failing intermittently with a `Not Found` error.

```rust
unsafe fn get_volume_handle_from_path(path_name: &Vec<u16>) -> Result<HANDLE, Error> {
    use std::os::raw::c_void;
    use windows_sys::Win32::{
        Foundation::INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE,
        Storage::FileSystem::{
            CreateFileW, FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS, FILE_SHARE_READ, OPEN_EXISTING,
        },
    };

    let file_handle = CreateFileW(
        path_name.as_ptr(),
        0,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        null(),
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
        null::<*mut c_void>() as HANDLE,
    );

    if file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE {
        return Err(Error::VolumeHandle(io::Error::last_os_error()));
    }

    Ok(file_handle as HANDLE)
}
```

e.g.

```rust
path_name = "C:\\".encode_utf16().collect::<Vec<_>>()

CreateFileW(
    path_name.as_ptr(),
    0,
    FILE_SHARE_READ,
    null(),
    OPEN_EXISTING,
    FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    null::<*mut c_void>() as HANDLE,
);
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: Not sure if this fixes the problem, but the documentation you linked says *"When opening a volume ... the `dwShareMode` parameter must have the `FILE_SHARE_WRITE` flag"* and *"When opening a volume ... the `lpFileName` string should be the following form: `\.\X:`"* and gives `"\\.\C:"` as an example string. Though its not clear whether you are actually trying to get a volume handle or just the directory at the root.

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, I've played with both the permissions of `dwSharedMode` and the `lpFileName` in the ways you describes, but the call still fails intermittently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings in Rust aren't zero-terminated. This is true for string literals as well. Unlike in C there is no implicit NUL character at the end of `"C:\\"`. When you're passing the pointer into the API it will continue reading past the end until it finds a NUL character.

Mind you, this is a memory safety bug that absolutely needs to be addressed.

Thankfully, the fix isn't very hard. You just need to add a NUL character manually. The following will do:

```rust
use std::iter::once;

let path_name = "C:\\".encode_utf16().chain(once(0)).collect::<Vec<_>>();
//                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ append NUL character
```

Alternatively, if you are passing a string literal, you can use the [`w!`](https://docs.rs/windows-sys/0.52.0/windows_sys/macro.w.html) macro instead that constructs a zero-terminated character string, like so:

```rust
CreateFileW(
    w!("C:\\"),
    // ...
);
```